# How to enable "reader-mode" in chrome using selenium and scrapy?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

You can enable the "reader-mode" by opening `chrome://flags/#enable-reader-mode` in Google Chrome.
[image: Enable Reader Mode]

Then, you can toggle the "reader mode" while browsing a webpage:

[image: Toggle reader mode]

How to get the "reader mode" version of a web page using Selenium and chromedriver?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: This was a while ago. I couldn't find any. Firefox had a way to do it by modifying the URL (prefixing by some string, IIRC) I used it as solution.

Answer (score -1):

Not really the answer you probably want. You can enable the "reader-mode" feature by using ChromeOptions.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-features=ReaderMode")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

Then you have to toggle it somehow. The Selenium documentation is quite clear that it is for not for testing browser functionality see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801432/839338 so you are left with using another automation tool like AutoIt https://www.autoitscript.com/site/ or Sikuli http://doc.sikuli.org/ to find and toggle the "reader-mode" menu item. I'm not sure how you go about that using scrapy.